# Effect of laxatives on pre-existing hard stool

Tags: gastroenterology, stools, constipation, laxative

I wonder if laxative medicines are able to soften pre-existing hard stool in colon or merely prevent them from being formed. I searched on the internet but found no helpful information. Sorry if the question is too basic.

I had encountered "stool softener" but found it somewhat ambiguous. After I wrote here, I noticed that [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laxative) uses "stool softener" only for emollient laxatives. It also states that "emollient agents prevent constipation rather than treating long-term constipation".

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*.

Comment: Specifically, any reasonable effort at researching laxatives should have produced stool softeners, which do exactly what it sounds like they do.

Comment: Thank you @CareyGregory. I had encountered "stool softener" but found it somewhat ambiguous. After I wrote here, I noticed that [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laxative) uses "stool softener" only for _emollient laxatives_. It also states that "emollient agents prevent constipation rather than treating long-term constipation". For my personal problem I've started taking Lactulose which is classified as a "hyperosmotic laxative". This is my first time using it.

Comment: Carey Gregory, can I ask you to reconsider this. The OP said he was searching but found the issue ambiguous. Stool softener can help in _preventing_ the formation of hard stool but not necessary in softening _already formed hard stool._ I consider it a valid and distinct _medical question_ because it challenges the usual logic, which may not work here.

Comment: @Jan If OP found the issue ambiguous, he needs to show us what he found and what's ambiguous about it. That's what site policy requires and the standard  others have been held to. If you want it reopened, then you need to vote to reopen.

Comment: @CareyGregory The thing is that I know so little about colon, the accumulation of stool there, and physiology in general. For example, when I read that lactulose causes absorption of water in colon and softens stool, to me it was an open question whether this softening is almost local or affects all stool in colon equally.

Comment: @apadana That's fine, then you should provide a link to that article, quote the relevant part(s), and explain what it is you don't understand. That demonstrates you've at least made an effort, which is all we require. Also, I get the impression from a comment you made above that you're asking about this in order to treat yourself. Please avoid that because that is strictly off topic.

Comment: @CareyGregory Is learning medicine for personal use off topic? Or is asking for medical prescriptions/advises off topic? Or both of them? Thanks.

Comment: @apadana Asking for medical advice is off topic. So in this example asking how laxatives work is okay, but asking which ones would be best for you is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard stool that stays in the colon for more than a couple of days is called "fecal impaction." Most *medical sources* recommend treating it with manually removing the stool (by a doctor, if necessary) and using *rectally* administrated enemas:

> Softening of hardened stool and stimulation of evacuation with enemas
>   and suppositories is often helpful...Most enema solutions contain
>   water and an osmotic agent. One such combination contains water,
>   docusate sodium syrup...and sorbitol... *Rectally* administered
>   solutions mechanically soften the impacted stool and the additional
>   volume gently stimulates the rectum to evacuate  *([Clinics in Colon and Rectal Surgery](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3348734/))*.

You can also check the "Fecal Impaction" part on [Mayoclinicproceedings.org](https://www.mayoclinicproceedings.org/article/s0025-6196(11)63796-8/fulltext).

According to [American Family Physician](https://www.aafp.org/afp/2015/0915/p500.html):

> Fecal impaction should be treated with *mineral oil or warm water
>   enemas.*

According to some studies, *oral* stool softeners may also help to remove hard stool ([ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/feces-impaction)).

> Oral disimpaction can be accomplished by high doses of stimulant
>   laxatives, docusate, mineral oil, and polyethylene glycol-electrolyte
>   (PEG) solutions. Osmotic laxatives such as lactulose or sorbitol can
>   be used in combination with other medication. *Oral disimpaction is
>   often associated with abdominal pain and colic, as well as an initial
>   increase in fecal soiling.*

The problem with *oral* softeners, stimulants and osmotic agents is that once you take them, you can't go back..They can cause severe bloating and abdominal or rectal pain, so one needs to judge carefully what to use. In fecal impaction, oral softeners can increase the amount of water in the intestine, but not necessary in the hard stool itself. This may cause pressure to push the hard stool out, which may not be successful and can be painful.